# Discord.js get user roles and save them in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How can i get a user roles and maybe save them in an array? i tried different ways, here's an example

```
const savedRoles = [];
const mentionedUser = message.mentions.members.first();

savedRoles.push(mentionedUser.roles.cache.array())
```

but it doesn't work and i cna't figure out how, i hope you can help

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? The code you provided works just fine, what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0):

`mentionedUser.roles.cache.array()` already returns an array of the members roles. Hence the `.array()` function invoke.

```
const savedRoles = mentionedUser.roles.cache.array();
```